# CDI : @alternative vs @Qualifiers

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

being new to CDI, i want to know the practical difference between an alternative and a 
Qualifier.

in [Weld reference](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html), it's stated that:

> 4.3. Qualifier annotations
>
> If we have more than one bean that implements a particular bean type,
>   the injection point can specify exactly which bean should be injected
>   using a qualifier annotation.

but while explaining the Alternatives, it is said:

> 4.7. Alternatives
>
> Alternatives are beans whose implementation is specific to a
>   particular client module or deployment scenario.

If I understood right, @Qualifier defines which implementations of the target bean get injected to the Injection Points.

on the other hand @Alternative describes a wish during deployment dependending on the client about whether or not an Alternatice to the standard (the "@default" I mean ) bean get Injected to the injection's point.

It is right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's right. You can imagine **qualifiers** as the basic weaving that you setup at development time, using annotations in your source code.

**Alternatives** allow you to overwrite this at execution time using the `beans.xml` file - a simple deployment artifact.

A typical scenario would be to use different `beans.xml` for different environments and thereby enable mock-alternatives for components that you don't want to execute on your local / integration environments.